# How to write a subquery which references the original table for an aggregation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, average

I have two tables tracking details on games and the performance of each team in a game.  The schema looks basically like this:

```
Game
- id
- date [TIMESTAMPTZ]
- team_a_id
- team_b_id

TeamStats
- game_id
- team_id
- stat_a [INTEGER]
- stat_b [INTEGER]
```

For each game, I want to summarise the performance of each team in all prior games.  The desired output would look like this, where the average columns are taken across all games with a date before the given game_id:

```
- game_id
- team_a_avg_stat_a
- team_a_avg_stat_b
- team_b_avg_stat_a
- team_b_avg_stat_b
```

I had thought that I would want a query something like the below, joining the game table to a query averaging stats for the given team over the given timeframe:

```
-- Example for team_a, would repeat with another join for team_b
SELECT g.id, ats.avg_stat_a as team_a_avg_stat_a, ats.avg_stat_b as team_a_avg_stat_b
FROM game g
    INNER JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT game_id, AVG(stat_a) AS avg_stat_a, AVG(stat_b) as avg_stat_b
        FROM teamstats its
            INNER JOIN game ig
                ON its.game_id = ig.id
        WHERE ig.date < g.date AND its.team_id = g.team_a_id
        GROUP BY its.game_id
        ) ats
        ON ats.game_id = g.id;
```

However, when I try the above query, I get zero results.  I would have expected one result for each row in the game table.

My initial attempt actually didn't have the lateral join - but when I tried that, I got an error message, which took me down the path of correlated subqueries:

```
/* ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "g"
LINE 8:   WHERE ig.date < g.date AND its.team_id = g.team_a_id
                          ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "g", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. */
```

What am I missing?

---

In addition, there is one constraint that I forgot to mention initially - I would like to be able to restrict the average to only consider dates within a certain time period (say, 90 days) of the game date.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Very good point - though I think you and GMB have captured what I was after regardless.  I will add sample data in a later edit if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use window functions - but you need a row frame so that only prior games are taken into account:

```
select g.id, 
    avg(ta.stats_a) over(
        partition by tsa.team_id 
        order by g.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) team_a_avg_stat_a,
    avg(ta.stats_b) over(
        partition by tsa.team_id 
        order by g.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) team_a_avg_stat_b,
    avg(tb.stats_a) over(
        partition by tsb.team_id 
        order by g.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) team_b_avg_stat_a,
    avg(ta.stats_b) over(
        partition by tsb.team_id 
        order by g.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) team_b_avg_stat_b
from game g
inner join teamstats tsa 
    on  tsa.game_id = g.game_id
    and tsa.team_id = g.team_a_id
inner join teamstats tsb
    on  tsb.game_id = g.game_id
    and tsb.team_id = g.team_b_id
```

Comment: @sapi: if you want the average for games in the last 90 days before this game, then just change the frame speficication of the window functions. You want a `range` frame instead of a `row` frame: `order by g.date range between interval '90 day' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding`

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.  One stupid question - why is it necessary to `partition by tsa.team_id` when `tsa` was an inner join on `tsa.team_id = g.team_a_id`?  Won't all non-null values in `tsa` already correspond to the right team_id?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think window functions do what you want:

```
select g.*,
       avg(ts_a.stat_a) over (partition by ts_a.team_id order by g.date) as avg_a_a,
       avg(ts_a.stat_b) over (partition by ts_a.team_id order by g.date) as avg_a_b,
       avg(ts_b.stat_a) over (partition by ts_a.team_id order by g.date) as avg_b_a,
       avg(ts_b.stat_b) over (partition by ts_a.team_id order by g.date) as avg_b_b
from game g join
     teamstats ts_a
     on ts_a.game_id = g.id and ts_a.team_id =  g.team_a_id join
     teamstats ts_b
     on ts_b.game_id = g.id and ts_b.team_id =  g.team_b_id
```

Comment: That does appear to be what I was after, thanks.  If I also want to put further conditions in place (e.g., restrict to dates within 90 days of the game date, not just all dates prior), would that be possible with a window function?

Comment: @sapi . . . A `where` clause in the query will filter both the result set and the data used for the `avg()`.  If you only want the result set filtered, then use a subquery and put the `where` in the outer query.